# Old electrical panel, what torques do I use?

Tags: electrical

Ok, so NEC 2017 makes it mandatory to torque all termination screws to spec.

But my panel is so old the original electrician's labels are in Latin.

It doesn't explicitly state torque values anywhere.  What values should I use?

Comment: The torque values were based on the screw thread and size I think there was a chart in the appendix's of the 2014 code I had to look them up a while back.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the tables in Annex I of the 2014 NEC (and I don't believe they went anywhere with the 2017 edition, either).  (Oddly enough, it specifies torques for slotted, hex, or square drives, but not Phillips or Torx.)

If you're looking for a more authoritative reference, UL 486A/B is the original source of this data (and also provides info about combo-headed screws and I presume things like Philips and Torx drives too).